# Generic class without type parameter in generic function

Tags: generics, typescript

Is there any way in Typescript to capture a generic class without its type parameter? I'm essentially trying to make a procedural style map function that operates on collection classes in my program like

```
interface Collection<T> {
    ...
}

function map<T, U, V extends Collection>(collection:V<T>, fn:(e:T) => U):V<U> {
    ....
}
```

but this doesn't work since the compiler wants me to put a type parameter on the Collection in map's generic list.

Essentially I want the type checker to know that if I call it on a `List<T>`, I get back a `List<U>`; call it on a `Set<T>`, I get a `Set<U>`; etc. Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take on this...

```
function map<T, U, V extends Collection<any>>(collection: V, fn:(e:T) => U) : Collection<U> {
    return null;
}
```

Compromise one: You can't re-use the type `T` in `V extends Collection<any>`. Ideally, you would have used `T` not `any`.

Compromise two: We are returning the less specific `Collection<U>` from the function. Ideally, you accept a general type and return a specific one, so this is a compromise.

No compromise version. You need an in type and an out type and you need a generic class so you can re-use the class types within the method type arguments:

```
class Mapper<T, U> {
    map<TIn extends Collection<T>, TOut extends Collection<U>>(collection: TIn, fn:(e:T) => U) : TOut {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Currerntly I'm using `function map<T, U>(collection: Collection<T>, fn:(e:T) => U) : Collection<U> { ... }` which ends up with the same type information as your first option but also enforces that the collection be made up of types that the function can accept, but I was hoping to make it more specific. Same with your second option, except I need to manually provide the T and U types when I instantiate the Mapper or else almost all the type information is lost.